# Objective-C blocks. Context captures the same variable/copies the same NSStackBlock

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am really confused with this one.

Here is my code:

```
for (SomeObject *obj in objects) {
    [self checkAndDownloadForObject:obj];
}

- (void)checkAndDownloadForObject:(id)obj
{
    switch (obj.type) {
```

inside of switch

```
... switch case scope

NSString *someId = [object.ID copy];    
NSInteger random = arc4random();
NSLog(@"working on id=%@", someId);

void (^flock)(NSData *data, NSError *error) = ^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"downloaded image for %@ image =%p", someId, data);
    NSLog(@"random = %u", random);
    [self useDataForId:someId withData:data];                   
};

NSLog(@"flock %@", flock);

[downloader download:someUrl completionHandler:flock];

void (^aBlock)(int rand) = ^(int rand){
    NSLog(@"block ra =%d random %u someId %@", rand, random, someId);
};

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    int ra = arc4random();
    aBlock(ra);
});

// end of switch case scope
```

When I run the code I see in logs:

```
2014-03-31 17:05:10.741 App[4142:60b] working on id=v7GhDlrq
2014-03-31 17:05:10.742 App[4142:60b] flock <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x17e86e00>
2014-03-31 17:05:10.787 App[4142:60b] working on id=tns_7Z-I
2014-03-31 17:05:10.788 App[4142:60b] flock <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x17ec85c0>
2014-03-31 17:05:10.824 App[4142:60b] downloaded image for v7GhDlrq image =0x18528a00
2014-03-31 17:05:10.825 App[4142:60b] random = 3993203783
2014-03-31 17:05:10.830 App[4142:60b] downloaded image for v7GhDlrq image =0x1852cc00
2014-03-31 17:05:10.831 App[4142:60b] random = 3993203783
2014-03-31 17:05:11.885 App[4142:60b] block ra =-2048013895 random 3993203783 someId v7GhDlrq
2014-03-31 17:05:11.886 App[4142:60b] block ra =513751079 random 727217709 someId tns_7Z-I
```

So as you can see `flock` block should capture `someId` which is not the same inside different calls of the bounding function and then execute something depending on it. `aBlock` works as expected but `flock` always uses the same (the first) `someId`. I have also put a random number to double check and again as you see the first value is copied and used for both calls.

```
[downloader download:someUrl completionHandler:flock];
```

method copies flock to the object which has copy property of the same block type, then downloads resource and then executes saved block.

EDIT1 :
If I pass block literal instead of making variable first

```
 [downloader download:someUrl completionHandler:^{
      ...block
 }];
```

In debugger if I set breakpoint I can see that the block is **_*NSStackBlock*_** and it has the same address(i.e. this is the same block literal) in different calls to bounding function. This means that I receive the same copy of the block as completion handler and therefore I print the same `someId` but in this case one question arises: Why do I receive the same stack block literal???

Could you please point me what is wrong with this code? Or why blocks behave like that in my case?

Comment: Does `downloader` copy or retain the block?

Comment: (What this looks like to me...) Your flock block is retaining NSString*someId when you pass it as a completion handler.   If you point NSString*someId to another string after that point, you should not expect the block that retained the object at NSString*someId to have switched to the string that NSString*someId now points to.   Now, if you had NSMutableString*someID and you mutated the string, things might be different, but NSString*someID is just a pointer to a copy of object.ID at some memory location.   You can't mutate the string at that location.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw downloader inside creates an object which has a copy property of the block. So it copies the block. I have also tried pass the copy of the 'flock' block to 'downloader' to ensure that the block is in the heap but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @stevesliva I don't want to mutate string. As you can see from logs at the different loop iterations I have different object.ID and therefore different 'someId'. What I expect is that the 'flock' block captures correct 'someId' in all iterations of the loop as 'aBlock' does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Why do I receive the same stack block literal?"

You don't.

Initially, the block is created on the stack. This "auto" variable ceases to exist when the method returns, no matter what. However, this stack block may/will be copied within `download:completionHandler:`.  Due to the loop, it is very likely that a new stack block will get the same address - yet it isn't the same as the previous, since that one has been deallocated.

What you are seeing in the logs though, seems a bit strange. I too believe, you should see distinct values for `someId`.

In a simple test case, I couldn't reproduce your issue. I suspect there is an issue elsewhere.

Comment: You are right. I have found an issue with download:completionHandler: implementation. Basically I have used the same block as completion block for all requests. The constant block address misled me to search in different direction. I accept your answer as the one which gave me hint to fix the issue. Thanks.